# PHP function does not work anymore

Tags: php

I have a php file called traitement.php in which I include first verifIban.php and then fonction.php

In traitement.php, I have that line:

```
//in traitement.php
include('../verifIban.php');
include('fonction.php');

echo 'test';
$controle = controleIBAN($tableIBAN,$tableBIC);
echo 'test1';
```

The echo is just for me to see where the problem is. controleIBAN() is in fonction.php
This fonction controleIBAN() has this line:

```
//in function.php
function controleIBAN($tableIBAN, $tableBIC){
    echo 'test2';
    $IBANVerifie = verif_iban_masse($tableIBAN[$i]);
    echo 'test3';
    //other commands
}
```

verif_iban_masse() is written in verifIban.php. And this function verif_iban_masse() has in particularly this line:

```
//in verifIban.php
function verif_iban_masse($str){
    echo 'test4';
    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT IBAN_national_id_length, IBAN_country_code, IBAN_total_length, IBAN_bank_identifier_position, fr_name, is_iban, is_iso FROM country WHERE iso_code = '".substr($str,0,2)."'");
    echo 'test5';
    //other commands
}
```

When I call traitement.php, I only get this output:

```
testtest2test4
```

So I think there is a problem with the BBD request. But when I do

```
$toto = verif_iban_masse('FR123456789');
echo $toto;
```

in the verifIban.php I have the correct output, so the BBD request is working...

This thing is working two weeks ago, we didn't change anything and now it does not...

If you can help me to find where is the problem.

Thank you

EDIT:
this is the start of verif_iban_masse()

```
function verif_iban_masse($str){
    include("../co_scripts/co_bdd.php");
    if (strlen(trim(str_replace(' ', '',$str))) < 8 OR strlen(trim(str_replace(' ', '',$str)))>35){
        return 'La longueur de la saisie est incorrect';    
    }
echo 'test4';
    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT IBAN_national_id_length, IBAN_country_code, IBAN_total_length, IBAN_bank_identifier_position, fr_name, is_iban, is_iso FROM country WHERE iso_code = '".substr($str,0,2)."'");
echo 'test5';
//other commands
}
```

So, I think the $bdd is from a connection to a database.

Comment: `return $response` from `verif_iban_masse` function

Comment: Where did `$bdd` came from at this point?

Comment: `$bdd` is undefined in your `verif_iban_masse()` function, and you don't return ANYTHING from that function, which means `$toto` can only ever be a `null`. But you say you get a correct response, so what you've posted above is NOT the actual code.

Comment: I will edit that...

Comment: Set some breakpoints and step through the code, you are the only one with enough information to solve this. Also, check your error logs